# How can create google pay for Ionic 4 (android / ios ) app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova-plugins, ionic4, google-pay

I have created google pay for web using following

URL : [Google pay for Web](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial)

I want to create same google pay for ionic 4 app 
which works on android and ios app

How can I create?
Any reference...
Please guide... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing the same issue for my new ionic 4 app

Comment: Did you end up finding out any more information on this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ionic to write your application, you'll need to make use of [native plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html) on Android in order to integrate Google Pay in your application (note that at the moment we do not maintain a library on iOS). Once in the JVM domain –both Java or Kotlin– you can follow the [Android tutorial in our dev docs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/).

Hope it helps.﻿