# GOOGLE PAY payment integration in ionic4

Tags: payment-gateway, ionic4, google-pay

I am working on a project and I have to integrate GOOGLE PAY payment gateway.

I could not find any articles which help me to start development to integrate GOOGLE PAY in Ionic. Referred some articles but not getting the exact solution.

If someone knows, kindly help me.

Comment: maybe this can help you : https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

Answer (score 2):

Google Pay isn't actually a payment gateway. It facilitates payments with payment methods stored in a Google Account through one of the supported Payment Service Providers (can be found in the middle of the page at https://developers.google.com/pay/api/).

With regard to working with Google Pay and Ionic, you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997582/12031739

> If you are using Ionic to write your application, you'll need to make use of [native plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html) on Android in order to integrate Google Pay in your application

Alternatively, if you do want to accept in-app purchases, consider [@Sam's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57592217/google-pay-payment-integration-in-ionic4#comment101643184_57592217).