# Ionic - Adding cards or passes to Google Pay

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, google-pay

I am developing a prototype app and I would like to add some dummy product cards or passes to apple wallet and to google pay.

I have found this for apple wallet: https://github.com/tomavic/cordova-apple-wallet#readme

Is there anything similar for google pay?
Is this possible?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57826424/8494980

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you need the cards or passes for, but some of the loyalty passes in the Google Pay app will allow you to put any membership id you want in (which can be used as a dummy pass).

Here is a link to instructions if you need it: https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7644069?hl=en